# What citation style allows the author to reference sources with superscript numbers?

Tags: citations

What citation style allows the author to reference sources with superscript numbers?

I'm at the very edge of my page limit. I'm allowed to use any citation style. I need something concise that can point to the relevant works I've listed on the works-cited page.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I often have found myself wondering this.
Not for avoiding page count, but because I find it more natural than referring to the authors.
I currently am using IEEE which does the number in square braces not superscript. Which by happy coincidence is the preferred style for the faculty i am studying in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming this is a coursework assignment. If you're that tight for space, are you sure you haven't written too much? Be careful that your finished piece doesn't "feel" cramped.

The *Nature* journal uses superscript numbers for in-text citations<sup>1</sup> and then references them in the bibliography like so:

1. Hynek, B. M. Implications for hydrologic processes on Mars from extensive bedrock outcrops throughout Terra Meridiani. *Nature* **431**, 156–159 (2004).

Comment: Yeah, IMO, the question is too big for the page limit. I don't think it feels cramped yet. I hope I'm right. Thanks for the tip. I'll use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LaTeX, you can refer to the following links for superscript citations:

- [Superscript citations without brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/superscript-citations-without-brackets-with-the-revtex4-1-document-class)
- [Using a superscript reference number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114833/biblatex-textcite-using-a-superscript-reference-number)